# is it possible to invoke c/c++ compiler from google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

For my final year project, i am planning to do a programming workbook for schools. In this the students will be given some programming questions, and they submit their code. I need to compile/run and check whether the out put is as expected or not. I am planning to use GAE for hosting this. Is it possible to access a C/C++ compiler in GAE? Or is there any other possible way suggested to implement this without compiler?

Comment: you could do it in the VM version of GAE but not the PaaS version.

Comment: I believe @PaulCollingwood is referring to Google Compute Engine, which should work for your needs. App Engine does not currently support C or C++ however